# BQ does not recognize column name when adding format Table.column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, format

Situation: I have two tables with the same column name called "Loyalty Number" and I would like to LEFT JOIN both tables using this column as the primary key.

Attempting to alias the column names as followed does not work as BQ will insert "customer_flight_data.Loyalty_Number" into the column instead of the actual number.

```
SELECT `customer_flight_data.Loyalty_Number` AS loyalty_number1,

FROM `case-study-airline-69374.customer_flight_activity.customer_flight_data`
```

OUTPUT:
column loyalty_number1

1. ```
   customer_flight_data.Loyalty_Number
   ```

I tried to remove the " ` " from the table.column but then I receive the

> error: Unrecognized name: customer_flight_data.

The only thing that works right now is:

```
SELECT Loyalty_Number FROM `case-study-airline-69374.customer_flight_activity.customer_flight_data`
```

Comment: you need to make a alias for the table like customer_flight_data

Comment: What do you mean by "BQ"?

Answer (score 0):

As nbk suggested you can either use an alias for the tables to identify the columns or use the complete table identifier for each column, without including the column into the qoutes.

```sql
--Complete Table identifier
SELECT `case-study-airline-69374.customer_flight_activity.customer_flight_data`.Loyalty_Number AS loyalty_number1,
FROM `case-study-airline-69374.customer_flight_activity.customer_flight_data`

--Alias
SELECT tablealias.Loyalty_Number AS loyalty_number1,
FROM `case-study-airline-69374.customer_flight_activity.customer_flight_data` as tablealias

--Example for the left join
SELECT 
  leftsidetable.Loyalty_Number AS loyalty_number1,
  rightsidetable.Loyalty_Number AS loyalty_number2
FROM `case-study-airline-69374.customer_flight_activity.customer_flight_data` as leftsidetable
LEFT JOIN `case-study-airline-69374.customer_flight_activity.customer_flight_data` as rightsidetable ON leftsidetable.loyalty_number = rightsidetable.loyalty_number
```